# How to separate a string by spaces and save the separated words regardless?

Tags: c

I have a program that separates words by spaces. I need to count which words in the text contain 4 different vowels. It didn't seem complicated, until I realized that I know how to save the divided words of the function (`strtok`) that returns the separated words, and of course, I can't count a single word because the function only prints. I don't know how to save the word individually to calculate how many vowels it contains and continue with the other words, one by one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

int main() {
    char phase[MAX];
    char temp [50];
    char delim[] = " ";
    
    printf("Ingrese un texto corto: ");
    gets(phase); //Short text with spaces
    printf("\n");
    
    for (i = 0; x < phase[x] != '\0'; ++x) {
        if (phase[x] == ' ' || phase[x] == '\t' || phase[x] == '\v') {
            //Detect space.
        }
    }
    
    char *ptr = strtok(phase, delim);
    
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr); //I need to keep all the words separate.
        
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Ingrese un texto corto: Ana come en el refrigerador.

Ana
come
en
el
refrigerador.
```

Comment: Define vowels chars for the language used in the example. Same as English (aeiou)?

Comment: If you know how to print a string, why don't you know how to do anything else with it? It's just a string.

Comment: See [Why the `gets()` function is too dangeous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/15168)

Comment: @जलजनक Yes, (A, E, I, O ,U).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code will solve the task. It's tempting to use `strtok()` again to search for vowels, but that would erase any information about word bounds from `strtok`'s internal memory. So, instead, use `strpbrk()` ([docs](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strpbrk/) and [more docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

int main() {
    char text[MAX];

    // all isspace() characters for "C" locale
    char delimiters[] = " \t\n\v\f\r";

    char vowels[] = "aeiou";

    printf("Input a string of text: ");
    // replaced unsafe gets() with more safe fgets()
    fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);

    char* word = strtok(text, delimiters);
    while (word != NULL) {
        // strpbrk() does roughly the same thing as strtok(), but it doesn't
        // modify a string nor does it remember anything on future calls
        char* ptr_to_vowel = word;
        int count = 0;
        while (NULL != (ptr_to_vowel = strpbrk(ptr_to_vowel, vowels))) {
            count++;

            // otherwise we'd stay on the same vowel
            ptr_to_vowel++;
        }
        printf("found %d vowels in %s\n", count, word);
        word = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

1. The `for` loop for counting spaces is incorrect.
2. We should have a separate function to count vowels.
3. *Never* use `gets` (use `fgets` instead).
4. The code did *not* preserve the original buffer as the code comments suggested.

---

> I need to count which words in the text contain 4 *different* vowels.

So, we can *only* count *unique* vowels in a word (e.g.):

1. `fleece` has only *1* unique vowel and *not* 3.
2. `great` has 2 vowels
3. `greet` has 1 vowel
4. `incombustible` has *4* [unique] vowels and *not* 5.

It's not totally clear, but I interpret this to mean that a candidate word has *at least* 4 unique vowels (i.e. it *could* have 5)

---

I had to refactor quite a bit of the code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 100

// vcount -- count _unique_ vowels
// RETURNS: number of _unique_ vowels
int
vcount(const char *str)
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiou";
    int vfreq[5] = { 0 };
    int vsum = 0;

    // loop through all chars in string
    for (int chr = *str++;  chr != 0;  chr = *str++) {
        // get lower case
        chr = tolower((unsigned char) chr);

        // is it a vowel?
        const char *vptr = strchr(vowels,chr);
        if (vptr == NULL)
            continue;

        // get index into frequency table
        ptrdiff_t vidx = vptr - vowels;

        // have we seen it before?
        if (vfreq[vidx])
            continue;

        // mark as already seen
        vfreq[vidx] = 1;

        // count new unique vowel
        ++vsum;
    }

    return vsum;
}

int
main(void)
{
    char phrase[MAX];
    char temp[MAX];
    const char *delim = " \t\v";

    printf("Ingrese un texto corto: ");
    // Short text with spaces
// NOTE/BUG: _never_ use gets
#if 0
    gets(phrase);
#else
    fgets(phrase,sizeof(phrase),stdin);
#endif
    printf("\n");

// NOTE/BUG: loop condition is incorrect
#if 0
    for (i = 0; x < phrase[x] != '\0'; ++x) {
        if (phrase[x] == ' ' || phrase[x] == '\t' || phrase[x] == '\v') {
            // Detect space.
        }
    }
#else
    int space_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; phrase[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        switch (phrase[i]) {
        case ' ':
        case '\t':
        case '\v':
            ++space_count;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Spaces: %d\n",space_count);
#endif

    // I need to keep all the words separate.
#if 0
    char *ptr = strtok(phrase, delim);
#else
    strcpy(temp,phrase);
    char *ptr = strtok(temp, delim);
#endif

    while (ptr != NULL) {
#if 0
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
#else
        printf("%s -- has enough vowels: %s\n",
            ptr,(vcount(ptr) >= 4) ? "Yes" : "No");
#endif

        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

---

For the input:

```
Ana come en el refrigerador.
```

Here is the program output:

```
Ingrese un texto corto:
Spaces: 4
Ana -- has enough vowels: No
come -- has enough vowels: No
en -- has enough vowels: No
el -- has enough vowels: No
refrigerador. -- has enough vowels: Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting words and then count vowels inside them, you can count vowels and upon a delimiter, check the vowel count and reset the count. This way, you do not need to modify the string. You actually do not even need an array to store the string: you can just read one byte at a time.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int mask = 0;
    int vowels = 0;
    int matches = 0;
    int done = 0;
    
    printf("Ingrese un texto: ");
    while (!done) {
        switch (getchar()) {
          case EOF:
          case '\n':
            if (vowels >= 4)
                matches++;
            vowels = mask = 0;
            done = 1;
            break;
          case ' ':
          case '\t':
          case '\n':
          case '\v':
          case '\f':
          case '\r':
            if (vowels >= 4)
                matches++;
            vowels = mask = 0;
            break;
          case 'a':
          case 'A':
            if (!(mask & 1)) {
                mask |= 1;
                vowels++;
            }
            break;
          case 'e':
          case 'E':
            if (!(mask & 2)) {
                mask |= 2;
                vowels++;
            }
            break;
          case 'i':
          case 'I':
            if (!(mask & 4)) {
                mask |= 4;
                vowels++;
            }
            break;
          case 'o':
          case 'O':
            if (!(mask & 8)) {
                mask |= 8;
                vowels++;
            }
            break;
          case 'u':
          case 'U':
            if (!(mask & 16)) {
                mask |= 16;
                vowels++;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", matches);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an alternative without a `switch` statement:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int mask = 0;
    int vowels = 0;
    int matches = 0;
    const char *vowels = "aAeEiIoOuU";
    
    printf("Ingrese un texto: ");
    while (!done) {
        int c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF || isspace(c)) {
            if (vowels >= 4)
                matches++;
            vowels = mask = 0;
            if (c == '\n' || c == EOF)
                done = 1;
        } else {
            char *p = memchr(vowels, c, 10);
            if (p != NULL) {
                int bit = 1 << ((p - vowels) / 2);
                if (!(mask & bit)) {
                    mask |= bit;
                    vowels++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", matches);
    return 0;
}
```